# Iteration again and again using loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, foreach, while-loop, nested-for-loop

I want to loop that iterates again and again,
like when You go from 0 to 4.
after it reaches 4 it again starts with 0.
Is it possible?

```
while True:
   while I <10:
       if I <=5:
        for c in a:
         run.chat(i)
         i+=1
       else:
           continue
```

Is it true code?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just reset the variable if it reaches the boundary:

```py
i = 0
while True:
    print(i)
    i += 1
    if (i > 4):
        i = 0
```